# Hide fifth row of a table

Tags: javascript

I have a html document with a table with five rows.

I want to hide the last row of the table when the selected value is not 1.

```
var tabla = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
var fila = tabla.rows[4];
var selección = document.getElementById('vinculo');
selección.onchange = function() {procesar_cambio()};
function procesar_cambio() {
    console.log('Procesar cambio. Ahora el valor es ' + selección.value + '.');
    if (selección.value === 1) {
        fila.display = '';
    } else {
        fila.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

The code is not hiding the last row of the table.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: I believe in your code `if (selección.value === 1)` is always *false*!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `fila.style.display = 'none';`

Comment: Happy to help :) If you hit the accept button I get more points :P